# How to set 4 android menu icon in a single row

Tags: android

> I want to set 4 menu icon in a sigle row.its showing 2 mene icon in one line and 2 icons in second line

---

This is my menu item code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Single menu item Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->


<item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
android:icon="@drawable/homf"
android:title="Home" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
android:icon="@drawable/shopcrt"
android:title=" Shopping Cart" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
android:title="Search" />


<item android:id="@+id/about"
android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
android:title="About" />


</menu>
```

Comment: as far as I know, you can't.

you could override menu button to show your cutom view with buttons.

Comment: It is a built in feature for android ICS but not previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could override menu button to show your cutom view with buttons, You can get some inspiration from the [Menu My way project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way). The source code is attached too.

[image]

```
/**
     * Manage  Menu Items Click.
     */
    @Override
    public void MenuItemSelectedEvent(CustomMenuItem selection) {

        switch (selection.getId()){




        case MENU_ITEM_FIRST:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToLaunch.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
            break;




        case MENU_ITEM_SECOND:
            //.....
            break;




        case MENU_ITEM_THIRD:
                    //....
            break;
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: thanks 4 help.but i wana when i click on icons so it start new individual  activity.how it will be through "Menu My project way" tutorial

Comment: @iqranaz you are welcome don't forget to mark the answer as accepted one, through this link you can see how to  accept  an answer